# Critique: Is there something I can do to make this illustration's ears look more symmetrical?

Tags: illustration, critique

People keep thinking the ears aren't the same size and shape, even though I just mirrored everything. Also, guides were used to double check all the parts with each other. Is it best for the sides to BE symmetrical or LOOK symmetrical?

[image: line drawing of a leopard]

Comment: just tossing this out there: maybe they should be LESS symmetrical?

Comment: I agree with both points so far, less symmetry, more detail. I'd also like to add that it looks like the inner ear is missing, that's where the detail and symmetry could be adjusted (maybe have one ear tilting away a teeny bit).

Comment: Well, it's for a logo and the client wants everything to be symmetrical. He thought the ears looked off, but I showed him this image with the guides.

Comment: Also, the drawing was based off of this picture: http://www.zoo.org/view.image?Id=3595 but I completely get what you're saying, without having more detail, about the inner ear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving them a tad more detail would help. That way the viewers eye has more reference points.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to add the inner-ear detail. You've provided the illusion of depth within the snout, this depth can be replicated within the ear whilst still maintaining symmetry.